# Conditions in NumPy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have an array `data` created with NumPy in Python with data

```
1 400
3 300
2 350
etc.
```

I want to calculate the mean of column 1 but only for those rows whose second column value is greater than 350.

I think it's something like

```
data[ > 350][:,1].mean()
```

I know that `> 350` is not correct but I don't know how to specify that it should check the second column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. You can select all the rows where the second column is greater than 350 by using:

```
data[:,1] > 350
```

This will create a numpy array of booleans (print it to see what it looks like. it's just `True` and `False` values in the shape of `data[:,1]` depending on whether they satisfy the condition), which you can use to index `data`:

```
data[ data[:,1] > 350 ][:,1].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
In [54]:

a[a[:,1]>350].mean()
Out[54]:
200.5
```

The boolean condition generates a mask you can use to filter the array:

```
In [55]:

a[a[:,1]>350]
Out[55]:
array([[  1, 400]], dtype=int64)
```

[`mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) accepts an axis param if you want to calculate mean for the entire array, or row-wise or column-wise.